# Simple script to open window and press hotkey

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, hotkeys

I want to make a simple script that will run when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>. This script will then press <kbd>WINKEY</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>. I cant seem to figure out a way to do this. I was trying batch files but `SendKeys` method does not support the WINKEY from what I gathered. This is Windows 7 or 10 (could be using either). Thanks

For those who don't know, <kbd>WINKEY</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> opens the third pinned program on the taskbar. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> is an internal command for that program. If anyone knows of another way to do this instead of faking the key presses, feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: Take a look at autohotkey. It will let you send either left or right windows keys (LWin on this page :https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm )

Answer (score 0):

I believe it isn't possible in batch, but as GregHNZ said, it is easily done in autohotkey. You can easily compile it into a exe, too!
Here's the code:

```
^k::
SendInput #3
SendInput ^a
```

If this doesn't work, try putting a `Sleep` command inbetween them:

```
^k::
SendInput #3
Sleep 1000
SendInput ^a
```

This just makes it wait for 1 second so the program can load (adjust the time to your needs, though!).

You can download Autohotkey [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/).